# How do I listen to an app that is deactivated from another app - Android

Tags: android, listener

I wanna make an app that listens another app's deactivating.
For example my app will be like:

- listening Facebook app...
- Facebook app is activated.
- Facebook app is deactivated. (that one which i want to catch.)

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BroadcastReceivers are probably where you want to look

Answer (score 0):

If by "activating" and "deactivating", you mean "moving to the foreground (resuming)" and "moving to the background (pausing)", there's no appropriate way to do what you're asking, since no broadcasts are fired when apps launch. You can use `ActivityManager` preferably in a `Service` like follows:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
    if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
        Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
    }
}
```

However, this method will take a toll on the device's resources and is not recommended.

Comment: Yes i mean resuming and pausing. I want to listen just one specific app. For example Facebook. I'll try your code soon.